# Nodejs Array counts commas as element

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I pass two arrays from my mongodb to my express server and then into my jade template. On this template the array get into an argument for a function of my client.js javascript and there array.length is longer because it counts `,` as an element.
In the db

```
..."voteup": [ 5, 6, 7 ], "votedo": [ 5, 4, 6, 1, 8, 2, 7, 3 ]...
```

In index.js

```
res.render('post', {vup: user.voteup, vdo: user.votedo, login: login}
                      ^ this is the array^
```

In post.jade

```
  script.
      fixVotes("#{vdo}", "#{vup}");
```

In client.js

```
    function fixVotes(down, up) {
  console.log(up.length); //Is larger
  for (var i = 0; i < up.length; i++) {

      document.getElementById("upvote" + up[i]).className = "disabled";
      document.getElementById("updis" + up[i]).className = "";

  }
  for (var i = 0; i < down.length; i++) {

      document.getElementById("downvote" + down[i]).className = "disabled";
      document.getElementById("downdis" + down[i]).className = "";

  }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like insufficient escaping, but we cannot really tell without seeing your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, this issue is arising because what you are assuming as an array is in string format actually. Please note that you can iterate through an array like this:

```js
var voteup = [ 5, 6, 7 ];

for( var i = 0; i < voteup.length; i++ )
{
  console.log( i + ": " + voteup[i] );
}
```

But if your array is in string format, then you may get unexpected output.  Please note that the `for` loop will still work, but the output will be different in case of a string ( I guess this is what's happening in your case ):

```js
var voteup = "[ 5, 6, 7 ]";

for( var i = 0; i < voteup.length; i++ )
{
  console.log( i + ": " + voteup[i] );
}
```

In this case, if you want to treat it like an array and print only the elements, you just need to first convert it to an array by using [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```js
var voteupString = "[ 5, 6, 7 ]";
var voteup = JSON.parse( voteupString );

for( var i = 0; i < voteup.length; i++ )
{
  console.log( i + ": " + voteup[i] );
}
```